# What is the difference between Model A and Model B?

Tags: pi-models

There are hardware differences and peripheral differences.  What can be accomplished or run on a Model B that cannot be done with a Model A?  Are expansion boards being designed to be compatible with both?  When available, other than cost, is there an advantage to ordering the Model A?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The model A only has 1 USB port and no Ethernet port, whereas the model B has 2 USB ports and has an Ethernet port.

Although the model B is the only one currently available, the Foundation's aim is to sell the model A at $25 and the model B at $35. Apart from the lower price, model A also offers small advantage of using less power, hence it can be powered by 500 mA power supplies.

Originally model A was only supposed to have 128MB of RAM - but it's now going to ship with 256MB (B will soon be shipped with [512MB for the same price](http://techcrunch.com/2012/10/15/raspberry-pi-mini-computer-now-shipping-with-ram-upgraded-to-512mb-from-256mb-same-tiny-35-price-tag/)). You may still see references to different memory in old literature.

Comment: Model A available in Europe as of today: http://www.raspberrypi.org/archives/3215

Answer (score 6):

Model A has 256Mb RAM, one USB port and no Ethernet (network connection). Model B  has 512Mb RAM, 2 USB port and an Ethernet port. [Source](http://www.raspberrypi.org/faqs) ( Under GENERAL )

Also checkout this [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) link for more details ( Under Specifications )

Answer (score 5):

sice 14.07.2014 the
[Model B has been replaced by Model B+](http://www.raspberrypi.org/introducing-raspberry-pi-model-b-plus/).

> **More GPIO**. The GPIO header has grown to 40 pins, while retaining the same pinout for the first 26 pins as the Model B.
>
> **More USB**. We now have 4 USB 2.0 ports, compared to 2 on the Model B, and better hotplug and overcurrent behaviour.
>
> **Micro SD**. The old friction-fit SD card socket has been replaced with a much nicer push-push micro SD version.
>
> Lower power consumption. By replacing linear regulators with switching ones we’ve reduced power consumption by between 0.5W and 1W.
>
> **Better audio**. The audio circuit incorporates a dedicated low-noise power supply.
>
> **Neater form factor**. We’ve aligned the USB connectors with the board edge, moved composite video onto the 3.5mm jack, and added four squarely-placed mounting holes.

Answer (score 2):

The Model A doesn't have a USB hub chip, Ethernet jack, nor a Ethernet chip; has fewer LED lights, 1 less usb port and half the RAM of the Model B; and has one or two very minute differences. However, it uses less power.